# Hide last 4 digits of credit card number in magento admin panel

Tags: javascript, magento, credit-card

This is the [code](http://pastebin.com/WBTKb8dz) [app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Ccsave.php ] to display credit card number in admin panel in magento `[sales > order ]`

To display all "credit card number" digits , except last four[hide last four digits ]", we have to edit the following line in above code.

```
Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number') => $info->getCcNumber(),
```

How to apply `substr()` for `$info->getCcNumber()`, to display all "credit card number" digits , except last four digits [hide last four digits ].

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a string *s*, you can get all but the last four digits as `s.substr(0, s.length - 4)`.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. can you please put this "s.substr(0, s.length - 4)" and edit entire line  "Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number') => $info->getCcNumber()," i am a new to javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. You have a javascript tag and magneto, so I don't know if you want that in javascript or PHP. See Amit's answer.

Comment: hi, amit answer worked. can you please use his answer and help me to hide first 4 digits. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number') => substr($info->getCcNumber(),0,-4).'***',
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot, fantastic boss, Can you please edit the same code for How to hide first 4 digits.

Comment: Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number') =>'***'. substr($info->getCcNumber(),4),

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please edit for this line : to hide last 4 digits : thats enough , i will not didturb you again :  $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());